# Add elements to a list of map using MEL/MVEL

Tags: mule, mvel

How can i add elements to a list of map using Mule MEL ? I have gone through the mule MEL documentation and [MVEL documentation](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/MVEL_Language_Guide#Lists) but could not find any examples for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MEL list should respond to standard Java methods. So the following should work:

```
myList.add(["Foo" : "Bar", "Bar" : "Foo"])
```

Comment: Yes, this does work, when used within setting of flow variables, it is important to return the flowVariable itself `#[flowVars.response.add(payload);flowVars.response]`